# Working of queue in ExecutorService's newFixedThreadPool()?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

As per [this explanation given in Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)), it says the following about

**public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)**

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown.

Which queue are they talking about? What if I don't use any queue in my multi-threaded application, like the below :

```
ExecutorService service;
service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
while(true){
try {
    s=ss.accept();
//new Thread(new MultithreadedInvocation(s)).start();     
    service.submit(new MultithreadedInvocation(s)).get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();   
}
```

***MultithreadedInvocation.java***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
public class MultithreadedInvocation implements Runnable{
//initialize in const'r
private final Socket socket;

public MultithreadedInvocation(Socket s) {
    this.socket=s;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {         
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int str;
        str=din.read();
        String name=din.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Client Name = "+name);
        System.out.println("Actual Client requested for file index "+str+".");
        ClientInfo ci = new ClientInfo();
        ci.ClientName=name;
        ci.ClientFileChoice=str;
        String fileName = new FileMapping().lookupFile(str);
        File tempFile=new File("C:\\Users\\server-3\\Desktop\\List\\"+fileName);
        dout.writeLong(tempFile.length());
        dout.flush();
        din.close();
        dout.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

What will happen to my 6th thread in this case, will it be automatically added to that `unknown queue`, or the thread-pool will terminate, and it won't function further??

Comment: You have kept `ExecutorService service` as **final** and also you are assigning new values to service `service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` in while loop. It is not clear what you are doing?

Comment: @NamanGala-Sorry, it was a mistake and I wanted to add that line inside comment, left it. Anyways, I've edited the question and removed `final` from the ExecutorService... Please answer now.

Comment: You have to take out your initialization of ExecutorService from while loop.

Comment: @NamanGala-Did that, what else? Thanks for helping. I request you to write an answer if you're quite confident enough...

Comment: I am just helping you to debug your code. See you have now initialized ExecutorService of fixed 5 thread. Now do one thing instead of using while for infinite loop, you can use for loop to execute it for 10 times and see how many threads are alive at a time.  And try to add thread number in `MultithreadedInvocation` constructor along with socket and assign different thread numbers into it. In your run method you can sysout entry and exit along with thead number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 5 threads then decide to run a loop that could call up to 30 threads, those processes are put into a queue and wait for a thread to become available.

Your 6th thread will wait until a previously submitted thread finishes or is cancelled.

[Previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274371/java-executor-service-thread-pool)

Comment: Where it'll wait? This is the main question? Any automatic default queue provided by JVM inside? Please care to explain that inner thing. I want the inner explanation.

Comment: @asad "Tasks are submitted to the pool via an internal queue, which holds extra tasks whenever there are more active tasks than threads"   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue by default. i did a System.out.println(executor.getQueue().getClass()).